# Is TCP checksum verification also offloaded to NICs?

Tags: tcp, interface, checksum

I understand that checksum calculation at the sender side is often offloaded to the NIC. Does this also happen for verification at the receiving end?

Answer (score 4):

There are *some* NICs that perform offloading, if configured to do so by the OS and drivers. This is *not* universal, and it can cause problems.

---

Host configurations and applications are off-topic here, but you can search for `tcp offloading` on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) to learn about the problems you may encounter, and how to disable the feature if necessary.